# Hyperlinks disabled when ProxyHTMLEnable is Set to ON

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, proxypass

I am using an application behind a reverse proxy (`proxypass` and `proxypassreverse`).

I don't understand why hyperlinks are disabled (unclickable) when I set `ProxyHTMLEnable` to `ON`.

Please note that the involved page contains:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

When I check the log, I find this message:

> Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter

Update:

That's how it looks like behind the proxy:

[image]

And that's how it should look like:

[image]

Be aware that I am using ProxyHTMLEnable because of relative paths.

When I do this, it works correctly:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://192.168.1.55:8080/myapp Keepalive=On timeout=600

ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://192.168.1.55:8080/myapp
```

When I do that, it doesn't:

```
ProxyPass /testenv/ http://192.168.1.55:8080/ Keepalive=On timeout=600

ProxyPassReverse /testenv/ http://192.168.1.55:8080/
```

Comment: I'd start from validating your pages to be sure they contain a correct HTML.

Comment: I don't have the source code of this app, unfortunately.

Comment: Should I use mod_rewrite?

Comment: Can we see an example of the content served when Apache logs “non-HTML content…”?

Comment: I can't attach images, not enough points, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When using `ProxyHTMLEnable ON` you're requesting that Apache rewrite the contents of the HTML that it proxies. It appears that in your case, you just want to reverse proxy so that your application is available at a different path. Should you need to alter the `href` or `src` attributes of the rendered HTML you're going to also need to set:

```
ProxyHTMLLinks a href
ProxyHTMLURLMap /testenv/myapp /myapp
```

Comment: When I analyze the generated source code, all links work except for the ones involved. The thing is that iframe tags should display BIRT reports, in the source code, they are not rewritten appropriately (/myapp instead of /testenv/myapp). I also included ProxyHTMLLinks  iframe src, but no result.

Comment: Try changing the `from-pattern` and `to-pattern` per the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmlurlmap) -- it usually takes me a few times to get it right personally J

Comment: I made some progress based on this interaction. One challenge was to make some iframe src point at the right relative path [SOLVED]. The next challenge is to activate those links. These links point at a "service" that takes a (BIRT) .rptdesign file that must be displayed as a .pdf file.
When I click on links in the "show source code" section, it redirects in a correct manner. I tried to use SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE (non-html) but it's not applicable for this issue.

Comment: If the answer provided solves the immediate question, can you please accept the answer? Then, if you have a *new* question that hasn't been resolved create a new question?

Comment: The original problem is still pending (I suspected the relative path issue, but that was a mere assumption). I tried to upvote your answer but I need 15 points of reputation.